# How to insert into table that has many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, many-to-many

вI have three tables. **permissions**, **roles** and a third table that references these two tables **role_permissions**. I want to insert a record into **roles** and **role_permissions** table.

How can this be done?

**permissions**

```
+---------------+-----------+
| permission_id |   name    |
+---------------+-----------+
|      1        | role_edit |
+---------------+-----------+
```

**roles**

```
+---------------+-----------+
|    role_id    |   name    |
+---------------+-----------+
|      1        |    admin  |
+---------------+-----------+
```

**role_permissions**

```
+---------------+-----------------+
|   role_id     |  permission_id  |
+---------------+-----------------+
|      1        |         1       |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you insert in roles table, then you insert in role_permissions where `role_id` - is a value returned from previous insert, for mysql, for example, is a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to be used, and `permission_id` is a value from permissions.
Like this (for MySql):

```
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES('<some_role>');
INSERT INTO role_permissions(role_id,permission_id) VALUES(SELECT 
LAST_INSERT_ID(),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others indicate you must create the `roles` and `permissions` before you can create role_permissions, assuming appropriate primary and foreign keys are in place. Unfortunately, Postgres does not provide a direct method to obtain the LAST ID for a table, further the last role or permission may often be the one you need.  What you need is to put a unique constraint on each of the name columns. Then to create the the role_permissions you can confidently get the appropriate `id` from the `name` you wish to combine. You join the two tables using those names.

```
insert into role_permissions(role_id, permission_id)
      select role_id, permission_id 
        from roles       r
        join permissions p  
          on (    r.name = 'group1' 
              and p.name = 'read all'
             );
```

You can also create a procedure that will handle the complete process: insert `roles`, insert `permissions` and insert `role_permissions` given just the names you want to combine.

```
create or replace 
procedure build_role_permissions( role_name_in text  
                                , permission_name_in text 
                                ) 
  language sql
as $$
    insert into roles(name) 
      values(role_name_in)
    on conflict (name) 
        do nothing; 
        
    insert into permissions(name) 
      values(permission_name_in)
    on conflict (name) 
        do nothing;  
        
    insert into role_permissions(role_id, permission_id)
      select role_id, permission_id 
        from roles       r
        join permissions p  
          on (    r.name = role_name_in
              and p.name = permission_name_in
             ) 
    on conflict (role_id, permission_id) 
        do nothing;
$$;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9b3494ac670cc3aee5e7a87f7706e4b3).